# Why is my shellscript execution of a gradle build behaving differently on jenkins than on cli?

Tags: shell, jenkins, gradle, build

When I perform `./gradlew build` on command line, gradle downloads and unzips the correct wrapper dist version and continues to download dependencies and build the project.

However when I perform the same within a shellscript on jenkins, it only downloads the gradle wrapper dist zip and tells me there are no dependencies.
How come no dependencies are seen this time ?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
```

I have already (first) tried using the gradle plugin on jenkins, same result.                 `ANDROID_HOME` is the same and set, I am using the same user on the cli.
Java version 8, Gradle 4.1, Android 25, Android build-tools 26.0.2

When i let jenkins invoke a script holding this build command it does work, but not directly. (current quickfix)

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: Try adding `-i` or if not enough info `-d` to the command. If this doesn't help you already, add the output to your question by editing the question or if too long by using some pastebin service and providing the link.

Comment: debug info is needed. I have tested both Gradle plugin as well as shell script, both works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works, I am not sure what changed to fix this other than the fact i have placed the commands in a function this time, but it is all working as desired.